# Ubuntu define correct virtual host on :81 port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, linuxmint

I'm trying to install `processmaker` on my local machine, i create `/opt` directory and paste this php script into that, not i should defin virtual host on my ubuntu os, for doing this action i have this apache configuration into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` as pmos.conf named which i want to use `127.0.0.1:81` to opening `/opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html` path

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName processmaker.dev
    ServerAlias www.processmaker.dev

    DocumentRoot /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <Directory "/opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html">
       AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
       AllowOverRide none
       Options FollowSymlinks
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ sysGeneric.php [NC,L]
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and `/etc/hosts` content is:

```
127.0.0.1          localhost
127.0.1.1          pishguy
127.0.0.1          processmaker.dev
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

after restarting apache

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

i dont get any error on shell, but typing `127.0.0.1:81` i get this error on FireFox:

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:81.
```

Comment: Can you try this from a shell: `telnet localhost 81`? Does it give any output?

Comment: @MrShunz i get this error: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: Why port 81? If you add a dns entry anyway there is no reason not to keep port 80.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider after change `81` to `80` i get this error: `Your connection is not secure. processmaker.dev uses an invalid security certificate.` and url can't open

Comment: If you configured SSL on port 80 you should fix that, that belongs on port 443. Self signed certificates are normal on localhost, they can be ignored. And you have to connect using your dns name for the virtualhost to work, not the IP.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i can't ignore that, how can i fix that?

Comment: We can't tell you that without seeing the rest of your config. But since this is obviously a development environment your question is off topic for this site. It will be closed and deleted in due course.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apache isn't listening to port 81.

Try, instead of `reload` to `restart` `apache2` process:

```
`systemctl restart apache2`
```

**Edit as per comment**

You should add the directive

```
Listen 81
```

to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, too (or add it to your `pmos.conf` just before
`<VirtualHost *:81>`).

Comment: I don't see any `listen 81` directive either.

Comment: @Mr Shunz  for `http://127.0.0.1:81/` url i get `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.` error and for `processmaker.dev` url i get `Your connection is not secure` error, I'm not sure why after opening `processmaker.dev` i have `https://processmaker.dev/` url on addressbar

Comment: @DolDurma this is another kind of problem. Do you have `mod_php` installed? Also make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled (`a2enmod rewrite` if using a Debian based distro).

Comment: @MrShunz yes, i dont have any problem for any other php scripts

Comment: @DolDurma Might be a permission problem then. Is `/opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html` accessible by apache process?

Comment: @MrShunz problem is not permission, i think problem is ssl on localhost which i should fix that `This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.`

Comment: @MrShunz `processmaker.dev uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is only valid for .`